# How to edit xml file using c++?

Tags: c++, xml

I have a "new_xml.xml" file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<people>
    <husband employed = "Yes">
    <name>MArk</name>
    <age>45</age>
    <wife>
        <wname>jenet</wname>
        <age>65</age>
     </wife>
 </husband>
</people>
```

Now, i want to add following line at the top of "new_xml.xml":

```
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "new_xmll.dtd">
```

So, suggest me how can i edit "new_xml.xml" using c++ and add above line into it

Answer (score 6):

You can just open a new file, write the string and the Content of the old file.

```
ifstream oldXML("path/to/old/xml");
ofstream newXML("path/to/new/xml");

newXML<<"<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM \"new_xmll.dtd\">"<<endl;  //Write first line
newXML<<oldFile;    //Copy Content of old file
```

You can also use a XML library if you want to Change any XML values. I like [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/) a lot

Comment: actualy i know about tinyxml but with that problem is it does not use DTDs. So thats why i wont favour using tinyxml

Comment: i used peace of code you suggested now i am getting new xml file having <!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM \"new_xmll.dtd\">,  now how will i copy it at the top of old file?

Comment: You Need to append the Content of the old file to the new file. My suggested code does that

Answer (score 0):

Then probably [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) or [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765540(v=vs.85).aspx) would be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use cycle with eof and read each line with getline(), when you find your line just add it.

Comment: can you suggest your point with example , it would be easy for me to understand.

Comment: sorry i am wrong, you will have to load the entire file into memory, adding to the top of the search string and overwrite the original file